# How do I use a has_one to refer to non primary key column? Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a table

```
  @primary_key false
  schema "user_reward_entries" do
    field(:id, Ecto.UUID, primary_key: true, read_after_writes: true)
    field(:amount, :integer)
    ...

    belongs_to(:transaction, Transaction)
    belongs_to(:user, User)

    timestamps()
  end
```

This table has a complex `primary key` made up of the `id` and the `user_id`. I am referring to the `transactions` table with the `belongs_to`.

In the `transaction` table I am trying to refer back to the `transaction` table.

```
  @primary_key false
  schema "accounts_transactions" do
    field(:id, Ecto.UUID, primary_key: true, read_after_writes: true)

    ...

    has_one :user_reward_entry, UserRewardEntry

    field(:completed_at, :utc_datetime_usec)

    timestamps()
  end
```

The error I get is `need to set :references option for association :user_reward_entry when schema has no primary key`. I then tried to use the `references` option, like this

```
    has_one :user_reward_entry, UserRewardEntry,
      references: UserRewardEntry,
      foreign_key: :transaction_id
```

and get another error `schema does not have the field SharedDb.Models.Rewards.UserRewardEntry used by association :user_reward_entry, please set the :references option accordingly`.

I have also tried

```
    has_one :user_reward_entry, UserRewardEntry,
      references: UserRewardEntry,
      foreign_key: :transaction
```

and get the same error.

I obviously don't understand what I need to do here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is stated in the documentation for [`has_one/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_one/3)

> - `:foreign_key` - Sets the foreign key, this should map to a field on the other schema, defaults to the underscored name of the current module suffixed by `_id`
> - `:references` - Sets the key on the current schema to be used for the association, defaults to the primary key on the schema

You don’t need to ever touch neither `references` (which expects a field btw, not a module) nor `foreign_key`, but the association name `belongs_to` in `reward_entries`. It currently mentions unknown to [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) `Transaction`.

That said, the following should work (actually, `foreign_key: :transaction_id` might be also needed):

```elixir
belongs_to :transaction, {"accounts_transactions", Transaction}
```